# batch file %cd% doesn't changed after changing current working directory

Tags: batch-file, cd

I wrote a batch file (windows os) that prints current working directory using %CD%, but even I change the current directory , the value of %CD% doesn't changed. This strange behavior happens to me in context of "IF" statement.

Here is a snapshot of the folders and the batch file Test.bat

[image]

I call the batch file from dir3.

It works ok if the code is as follows :

```
@echo off 
@echo %CD%
cd /d c:\temp\dir1
@echo %CD%
```

[image]

but in the follow code it doesn't work as shown in the snapshot of the prompt window. Even after changing the current working directory it prints the first one - c:\temp\dir3.

```
@echo off 
if exist "c:\bom" (
   @echo file exist already
) else (
@echo %CD%
cd /d c:\temp\dir1
@echo %CD%
)
```

[image]

Comment: firstly, rather use backslash and not forward slash. cd /d "c:\dir1" as windows use backslash by default. I would also like you to provide me with a screenshot if possible that it does not echo the new current directory. Also, unless you want to use the actual variable `%cd%` you could just do `cd` without having to `@echo %cd%`

Comment: `cd` without any parameters will print the current working directory. No need to use `@echo %CD%`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - thanks, I added snapshots. After checking according to your comment, I found that it happens only within the IF context as shown.

Comment: ok, that is WAY different now that you added the loop.. You need delayed expansion or just use `cd`

Comment: This is not 'strange behaviour' for a batch file.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/12343998)》and delete your duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are lacking `delayedexpansion` here. Here are 2 ways though:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist "c:\bom" (
  @echo file exist already
) else (
  @echo !CD!
  cd /d c:\temp\dir1
  @echo !CD!
)
```

or just use `cd` without `echo`ing the variable `%cd%`

```
@echo off 
if exist "c:\bom" (
  @echo file exist already
) else (
  cd
  cd /d c:\temp\dir1
  cd
)
```